# C# API JSON Invalid input

Tags: c#, json, fedex

I want to extract the FedEx tracking information from this FedEx tracking number: 534982493439

However, I keep on getting the error below:

> {"transactionId":"f332d21f-6a13-4372-896c-5b45a19ffe99","errors":[{"code":"INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION","message":"Invalid field value in the input"}]}

I am following this guide with the following link and code sample below:
https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-ng/catalog/track/v1/docs.html#operation/TrackingDocuments

```
var client = new RestClient("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ");
request.AddHeader("X-locale", "en_US");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
// 'input' refers to JSON Payload
request.AddParameter("undefined", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I am able to get the access token, but I can't get any tracking information because of the error mentioned above.

Why do I keep getting this error and how can I fix it?

> {"transactionId":"f332d21f-6a13-4372-896c-5b45a19ffe99","errors":[{"code":"INVALID.INPUT.EXCEPTION","message":"Invalid field value in the input"}]}

This is what I have so far:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FedExGetTrackingInfo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public class APITokenInfo
        {
            public string access_token { get; set; }
            public string token_type { get; set; }
            public int expires_in { get; set; }         
        }

        private void btnGetTrackingInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            request.AddParameter("client_id", "XXX");
            request.AddParameter("client_secret", "XXX");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);




            rtbResponse.Text = response.Content;

            var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APITokenInfo>(rtbResponse.Text);

            rtbToken.Text = o.access_token;




            var clientX = new RestClient("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/track/v1/trackingnumbers");
            var requestX = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            requestX.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + rtbToken.Text);
            requestX.AddHeader("X-locale", "en_US");
            requestX.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var apiInput = new { trackingNumberInfo = "534982493439", includeDetailedScans = "false" };
            requestX.AddParameter("undefined", apiInput, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse responseX = clientX.Execute(requestX);


            rtbResults.Text = responseX.Content;
        }
    }
}
```

=============UPDATE==================

I changed this

```
 var apiInput = new { trackingNumberInfo = "534982493439", includeDetailedScans = "false" };
```

to

```
requestX.AddParameter("undefined", apiInput, ParameterType.RequestBody);
requestX.AddParameter("application/json", rtbJSON.Text, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

The Text property value of the richTextbox rtbJSON object is

```json
 {
  "trackingInfo": [
    {
      "trackingNumberInfo": {
        "trackingNumber": "534982493439"
      }
    }
  ],
  "includeDetailedScans": true
}
```

I SOLVED IT LOL  I GOT THE RESULTS

> {"transactionId":"1f3308c9-eed7-4324-84ed-13cd88d25f54","output":{"completeTrackResults":[{"trackingNumber":"534982493439","trackResults":[{"trackingNumberInfo":{"trackingNumber":"534982493439","trackingNumberUniqueId":"2459550000~534982493439~FX","carrierCode":"FDXE"},"additionalTrackingInfo":{"nickname":"","packageIdentifiers":[{"type":"DEPARTMENT","values":["3(JC)"],"trackingNumberUniqueId":"","carrierCode":""},{"type":"SHIPPER_REFERENCE","values":["T736472/6032817"],"trackingNumberUniqueId":"","carrierCode":""}],"hasAssociatedShipments":false},"shipperInformation":{"contact":{},"address":{"city":"Hebron","stateOrProvinceCode":"KY","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"}},"recipientInformation":{"contact":{},"address":{"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"}},"latestStatusDetail":{"code":"DL","derivedCode":"DL","statusByLocale":"Delivered","description":"Delivered","scanLocation":{"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"}},"dateAndTimes":[{"type":"ACTUAL_DELIVERY","dateTime":"2021-12-03T12:55:00-10:00"},{"type":"ACTUAL_PICKUP","dateTime":"2021-12-01T17:38:00-05:00"},{"type":"SHIP","dateTime":"2021-12-01T00:00:00-06:00"},{"type":"ACTUAL_TENDER","dateTime":"2021-12-01T17:38:00-05:00"}],"availableImages":[{"type":"SIGNATURE_PROOF_OF_DELIVERY"}],"specialHandlings":[{"type":"DELIVER_WEEKDAY","description":"Deliver Weekday","paymentType":"OTHER"}],"packageDetails":{"packagingDescription":{"type":"YOUR_PACKAGING","description":"Your Packaging"},"sequenceNumber":"1","count":"1","weightAndDimensions":{"weight":[{"value":"26.0","unit":"LB"},{"value":"11.79","unit":"KG"}],"dimensions":[{"length":36,"width":31,"height":11,"units":"IN"},{"length":91,"width":78,"height":27,"units":"CM"}]},"packageContent":[]},"shipmentDetails":{"possessionStatus":true,"weight":[{"value":"26.0","unit":"LB"},{"value":"11.79","unit":"KG"}]},"scanEvents":[{"date":"2021-12-03T12:55:00-10:00","eventType":"DL","eventDescription":"Delivered","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","postalCode":"96819","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"HNLA","locationType":"DELIVERY_LOCATION","derivedStatusCode":"DL","derivedStatus":"Delivered"},{"date":"2021-12-03T08:39:00-10:00","eventType":"OD","eventDescription":"On FedEx vehicle for delivery","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","postalCode":"96819","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"HNLA","locationType":"VEHICLE","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"},{"date":"2021-12-03T07:06:00-10:00","eventType":"AR","eventDescription":"At local FedEx facility","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","postalCode":"96819","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"HNLR","locationType":"DESTINATION_FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"},{"date":"2021-12-02T22:20:00-10:00","eventType":"AR","eventDescription":"At destination sort facility","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","postalCode":"96819","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"HNLR","locationType":"SORT_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"},{"date":"2021-12-02T18:11:00-06:00","eventType":"DP","eventDescription":"Departed FedEx hub","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"MEMPHIS","stateOrProvinceCode":"TN","postalCode":"38118","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"MEMH","locationType":"FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"},{"date":"2021-12-02T04:26:00-06:00","eventType":"IT","eventDescription":"In transit","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"MEMPHIS","stateOrProvinceCode":"TN","postalCode":"38118","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"MEMH","locationType":"FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"},{"date":"2021-12-02T04:20:00-06:00","eventType":"IT","eventDescription":"In transit","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"MEMPHIS","stateOrProvinceCode":"TN","postalCode":"38118","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"MEMH","locationType":"FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"},{"date":"2021-12-01T23:25:00-06:00","eventType":"AR","eventDescription":"Arrived at FedEx hub","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"MEMPHIS","stateOrProvinceCode":"TN","postalCode":"38118","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"MEMH","locationType":"FEDEX_FACILITY","derivedStatusCode":"IT","derivedStatus":"In transit"},{"date":"2021-12-01T17:38:00-05:00","eventType":"PU","eventDescription":"Picked up","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"city":"HEBRON","stateOrProvinceCode":"KY","postalCode":"41048","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationId":"LUKA","locationType":"PICKUP_LOCATION","derivedStatusCode":"PU","derivedStatus":"Picked up"},{"date":"2021-12-01T15:58:54-06:00","eventType":"OC","eventDescription":"Shipment information sent to FedEx","exceptionCode":"","exceptionDescription":"","scanLocation":{"streetLines":[""],"residential":false},"locationType":"CUSTOMER","derivedStatusCode":"IN","derivedStatus":"Initiated"}],"availableNotifications":["ON_DELIVERY"],"deliveryDetails":{"actualDeliveryAddress":{"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"locationType":"RECEPTIONIST_OR_FRONT_DESK","locationDescription":"Receptionist/Front Desk","deliveryAttempts":"0","receivedByName":"E.ED","deliveryOptionEligibilityDetails":[{"option":"INDIRECT_SIGNATURE_RELEASE","eligibility":"INELIGIBLE"},{"option":"REDIRECT_TO_HOLD_AT_LOCATION","eligibility":"INELIGIBLE"},{"option":"REROUTE","eligibility":"INELIGIBLE"},{"option":"RESCHEDULE","eligibility":"INELIGIBLE"},{"option":"RETURN_TO_SHIPPER","eligibility":"INELIGIBLE"},{"option":"DISPUTE_DELIVERY","eligibility":"INELIGIBLE"},{"option":"SUPPLEMENT_ADDRESS","eligibility":"INELIGIBLE"}]},"originLocation":{"locationContactAndAddress":{"address":{"city":"HEBRON","stateOrProvinceCode":"KY","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"}},"locationId":"LUKA"},"destinationLocation":{"locationContactAndAddress":{"address":{"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"}},"locationType":""},"lastUpdatedDestinationAddress":{"city":"HONOLULU","stateOrProvinceCode":"HI","countryCode":"US","residential":false,"countryName":"United States"},"serviceDetail":{"type":"PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT","description":"FedEx Priority Overnight","shortDescription":"PO"},"standardTransitTimeWindow":{"window":{"ends":"2021-12-02T17:00:00-10:00"}},"estimatedDeliveryTimeWindow":{"window":{}},"goodsClassificationCode":"","returnDetail":{}}]}]}}

Comment: At the face value, just checking this is a valid Parameter input? `request.AddParameter("undefined", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);`?

Comment: Yes it is valid

Comment: How did you solve it?  I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just to help others searching for "Invalid field value in the input" on Fedex API integration.

I believe this happens when the API is expecting an array but receives and object and vice versa.  Don't focus on your data values but double check when arrays are expected.  Wish their error message said something about data type instead of value.

Comment: Wish it told you WHICH FIELD WAS INVALID!  Who created this error message, Saddam Hussein?